# Circular Seekbar with two thumbs

Tags: java, android

I was looking at a project on GitHub (see link below) about a circular seekbar and was wondering if it was possible to add a second thumb to it and additionally not have any limits to where you can move the thumbs (no start and end). Is that possible? I was looking at the source code but I am rather new to android development and so I was wondering if anyone knows how to implement this idea? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

My idea is to create a time-frame/window picker (the circular seekbar would be like a clock)

[This is the project on GitHub](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar)

Comment: After thinking about it, the idea might not be that great after all, if one is interested in including all 24 hours of a day...(not just twelve like a clock)